# where do i store large amount of images for a website

Tags: asp.net

I am a novice when it comes to websites

i'm developing a website for a real estate company this site will have loads of pictures of houses for sale

i thought of storing the images in a database but i have been advised to use a folder instead

which would be the best method to use a database or folder considering that there will be images added to the site on a daily basis ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best performance wise to use the *filesystem*, and safety-management wise it's better to use the *DB* (backups and consistency).

However, in *SQL Server 2008*, you can apply the `FILESTREAM` attribute to a varbinary column, and *SQL Server* then stores the data for that column on the local *NTFS file system*.

Read about [FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

---

Also refer to the following:

[FILESTREAM Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)

[Getting Traction with SQL Server 2008 Filestream](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would add the images into the file system as adding them to a database will bloat the database and not give you any advantages over the file system.

When storing them in the file system, you can create folders based on a unique id linked to the record in the database. This then means that you can add any media types to this folder and then recall/display them based on the unique id. It also means that you can display multiple images by simply coding your system to display all images in the folder.

Also, look into a content delivery network (CDN) which will cache the images and give you better performance when it comes to loading speed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them in a database, this is highly ill advised for performance reasons.

Store them in a folder, and store the location to the image in the database.

Comment: Use the property ID as part of the filename to avoid collisions. (assuming your properties have an identity ID field).

Comment: can u explain reasons please?

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a folder. If you have lots of images, a strategy to create subfolders (id, hash, uuid, etc) will be helpful.

```
imagefolder
+--00
|   +--00
|   +--01
|   ...
|   +--FF
+--01
+--02
```